# Custom template for post type not working

Tags: custom-post-types, single

I have a post type `shopping` and in my `single.php` I am trying to get a certain template for this post type. So I did:

```
\\ in the single.php
get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
```

and in `template-parts` directory, I created a file named `content-shopping.php`. But no matter what, the single template used is the default `content.php`.

However, if I do something like this:

```
if ( 'shopping' === get_post_type() ) {
  get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-shopping' );
}else{
  get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
}
```

then the template is used for that post type. I am not sure why the first method is not working. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`get_post_format` and `get_post_type` are completely different.

Post Formats can be one of the following:

- 'standard' (default one)
- 'aside'
- 'chat'
- 'gallery'
- 'link'
- 'image'
- 'quote'
- 'status'
- 'video'
- 'audio'

And `shopping` is the **post type** you have created and not **post format**. You can add post format for the post type(shopping) like this

```
add_post_type_support( 'shopping', 'post-formats' );
```

Comment: ah, stupid me. I thought by creating the post type, I added a special post format beside those. In the first example, I just replaced post format with `get_post_type` and it works.